# How to diagnose lost ground issues?

Tags: electrical

After installing two LED recessed light fixtures our house lost ground. We have disconnected the circuit for the LED fixtures yet the 3-prong outlet tester now shows an open ground on all outlets in the house. We have had some flickering lights in the past so this may be an older issue that we just discover accidentally but we are not sure if it is actually the result of anything we did as we have no ground with the specific circuit off.

After receiving some feedback, I found that the ground wire is connected to the main water line and that the main water line has some corrosion on it. I cleaned it with a metal brush. The confusing thing is that the the outlet tester shows a flickering light here and then, yet the multi-meter gives proper readings (124 between Live and Ground, 124 between Live and neutral, and 0 between Neutral and Ground).

[image: Main Panel]

[image: Ground wire at the Water Line]

[image: Outlet tester]

The house was inspected by both a home inspector pre-purchase and then by an electrician after to install a new panel (this was two years ago).

We have called an electrician but we live in a rural area and the next available appointment is a week from now and we are a bit worried about how unsafe this may be. We are trying to understand the issue so any info would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you meant when you said "0 now but before that it was ~124" ??

Comment: Hi. I meant to say that I tested with a multi meter before I cleaned the ground wire and i had 0. I am going to edit the question to make sure that is not confusing.

Comment: That makes a little sense but I think something is still missing.  Even if you had a corroded ground connection, the neutral bond in the panelboard should provide a return path for any ground wire in your house.  Where exactly did you measure zero?

Comment: The last time I measured zero between Neutral and Ground; 124 between Live and Neutral; and 124 between Live and Ground. I set the multi-meter to 200 in V~. The tester shows no light or a dim/flickering light. That goes for all outlets in the house.

Comment: Even though I do a lot of DIY work, especially electrical, I would call an electrician to handle any problems with the ground system connected to my main panel.  Why?  Because it's not something that I have, or ever could have, much experience with.   You can't "get good at" this with DIY when you only do it once or twice per lifetime.  it's hugely safety-critical, and it's *impossible to test*.  It relies heavily on training and experience, that only a professional could have.

Comment: This panel was installed two years ago by an electrician? Were they actually licensed? You shouldn’t have Homeline or GE breakers in an Eaton panel (although Eaton does make breakers that are listed for use in other panels). There are also some red wires on single-pole breakers that suggest MWBCs that should be handle tied. Finally, ending up with only two free spaces after panel replacement is terrible. Going bigger (like 40 space) would have only been a trivial parts price difference.

Comment: Thanks! @nobody: do you think this is a safety issue? I think I solved the issue but I may still have the electrician come and triple check everything thus what you are saying could be very useful.

Comment: I would _absolutely_ recommend getting a 2nd electrician in to inspect the entire system to make sure everything is done correctly and is good to go. Despite discovering that your Magic 8-Ball, errrr... outlet tester was broken, the fact that you have foreign breakers in your Eaton panel is concerning at least. **Get it inspected**

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan! I have scheduled an inspection. If there is anything I learn that could be of use for others, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Faulty Outlet Tester

If you have normal multi-meter indications and no other grounding problems, then the flickering light in your outlet tester isn't working.

A high resistance ground will show lower than normal voltage on a multi-meter.

Ground and neutral are bonded together in your Eaton panelboard, so you can expect similar results from ground and neutral when everything is working normally.

Comment: You were right that it was a faulty outlet tester. I just came back from the store with a new one and the ground has been restored. Thanks again!